# CustomListBox duplicated items

Tags: c#, visual-c#-express-2010

Help!
I'm trying to make a custom ListBox control that can be use to choose a DashStyle from. The problem is when I drag the custom component to my form it adds the items (which is ok), but when I run the program it add the items again, giving me duplicates.
Here is my code:

```
namespace Help
{
    public partial class LineStyleListBox : ListBox
    {
        private Pen[] pens;
        string[] styleNames;
        public LineStyleListBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();               
            styleNames = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(DashStyle));
            pens = new Pen[styleNames.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i != pens.Length; i++) 
            {
                pens[i] = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 1);
                pens[i].DashStyle = (DashStyle)i;
            }                          
            Items.AddRange(styleNames);          
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any help, or comments. Thanks!

Comment: May be just check if Items is empty? if (Items.Count <= 0) Items.AddRange(styleNames);

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around by doing this -

```
if(LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
            Items.AddRange(styleNames);
```

Somehow it still show the items when I add the control to my form. 
Can someone explain why? And if there is a better way. Thanks

Comment: I think you've got it wrong. If you want the items to be added only when the control is used in non designtime mode. Then the code should've been: `if(LicenseManager.UsageMode != LicenseUsageMode.Designtime) { Items.AddRange(styleNames); }` (notice the not equal comparison). Tips: You should've updated your question instead of posting an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the constructor of the control like this:

```
public LineStyleListBox()
{
  InitializeComponent();      

  // do not add items if the control is in design mode
  if (LicenseManager.UsageMode == LicenseUsageMode.Designtime)
    return;

  styleNames = System.Enum.GetNames(typeof(DashStyle));
  pens = new Pen[styleNames.Length];
  for (int i = 0; i != pens.Length; i++) 
  {
    pens[i] = new Pen(new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 1);
    pens[i].DashStyle = (DashStyle)i;
  }                          

  Items.AddRange(styleNames);          
}
```

Answer (score 0):

VS Designer serializes the items. When application starts the styles added at 1st in the LineStyleListBox constructor and 2nd - in InitializeComponent() of the Form.

If you want see the styles at Desing time and don't want to have any new styles

```
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public new ListBox.ObjectCollection Items
{
    get { return base.Items; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach would be to use a `bool hasAdded;`, and set it to true once you have added the items, checking it before you add any more.

Hope this helps someone!